# Hot Network Questions favicons are completely shuffled around

Tags: bug, hot-questions, favicon

A few of the Hot Network Questions icons are shuffled around for some reason. For instance, "Really, really hard wood - how is it cut and formed" is not a Workplace link, it is a worldbuilding link. Then "Using a fake name for book" is a writing link rather than a worldbuilding one. "Is main a valid Java identifier?" is Stack Overflow, not some general Stack Exchange.

I've opened [Chrome refresh right-click reload options not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131532/) in an incognito window to test with no cache and I can still reproduce this.

[image: screenshot of broken favicons]